# asp.net mvc access to IResourceProvider from Application start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there way access to `IResourceProvider` from Application start?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You can use static method HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject instead.